# Get an array wich contains the post_name of every post that has the custom post_type "pelicula"

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, array

I need an array that contains all the posts names that match with the post_type"pelicula"

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php // query for your post type
    $post_type_query  = new WP_Query(  
        array (  
            'post_type'      => 'pelicula',  
            'posts_per_page' => -1
        )  
    );   
    // we need the array of posts
    $posts_array      = $post_type_query->posts;   
    // create a list with needed information
    // the key equals the ID, the value is the post_title
    $post_title_array = wp_list_pluck( $posts_array, 'post_title', 'ID' );
    var_dump($post_title_array);
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [get_posts( $args )](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) that uses [WP_query($args)](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) to create an array of posts.

```
$posts_array = get_posts( 'post_type' => 'pelicula', 'posts_per_page' => -1 );

$post_title_array = wp_list_pluck( $posts_array, 'post_title', 'ID' );
```

**Note:** `post_name` is the unique `slug` for the post and `post_title` refers to the Title of the post. So you may adjust above code accordingly.